# PHP mysql query does not work

Tags: php, mysql, get

My problem is the following:
I want to display a single row from a sql database

Link is: /index.php?wh=1

code:

```
$wh_id=($_GET["wh"]);
$wh_qr=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM warehouse WHERE warehouseid = '$wh_id';");
```

on `echo $wh_qr` i get only Resource id #5, not the value of the "name" in the Database.

What do i wrong?

Comment: You need to do some type of loop, either a `while` or `foreach` to iterate through results found (if any exist). You can't just `echo` a query on its own. Show us your full code.

Comment: its only one result?, and if it where more than on, it has to select only on. cuz it should display in the end something like:

"You are currently on: `<?php echo $wh_qr ?>`"

Comment: I believe what I mentioned can be found in the answer(s) given below.

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: That is the funniest SQL injection comic I've ever seen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to do the following.  I also added in some error handling for you.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("<HOST>", "<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>", "<DATABASE_NAME");
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT name FROM warehouse WHERE warehouseid = '$wh_id';");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$echo $row["name"];
```

Then output the $row and you should get what you're looking for. `$row` will be an array of strings, one per column that you expected from your query.

Also, all of the functions you are using are deprecated.  You should be using the `mysqli*` functions.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index2.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index2.php on line 20

Comment: If you can provide your database connection variable name, that simply needs to be provided to the `mysqli_fetch_row` function call.  I will update my post to include that ...

Comment: yes, but instead of `mysql_connect`, it would be `mysqli_connect`, whatever variable you store that connection to, is what gets passed as the `$link` variable I specified in my `mysqli_fetch_row` function call.

Comment: @SlyRaskal mysqli_fetch_row expects 1 parameter only and not 2. It expects the mysqli result only.

Comment: No, I've made a correction to my answer for you, the `$link` parameter should be passed tot he mysqli_query function as well.  In some cases it's assumed.

Comment: @AliTrixx, I am aware of that, I made a typo in my edits. it is now corrected.  Thank you.

Comment: @SlyRaskal Not really, I still see mysqli_fetch_row with 2 parameters.. `mysqli_fetch_row($link,$result);`

Comment: Thanks, works, so basically just add "$link" to all the querys, and add an i to mysql?... is the rest the same?

Comment: I believe you've got it @user3101966, try to use the `mysqli_*` functions wherever possible because  the `mysql_*` functions have been depcrecated. The `$link` variable that contains the connection information should be passed to the other respective `mysqli_*` function calls where necessary.  The PHP documentation is a great place to learn about which parameters are necessary when making function calls,and in some cases you will find shortcuts to doing this stuff as well. ;) Cheers.

Comment: @AliTrixx, well then you should refresh the page. ;) I made the edit before you posted your comment

Comment: @AliTrixx was riht, mysqli_fetch_row has only one parameter, but i used assoc(), that works. 
Tanks for your help, this is the working solution :)

Comment: gah, my page edit must have not submitted earlier.  Fixed it now.  Sorry about that @user3101966.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query` returns a `mysql result` and not a string so you could echo, what you need to do is

```
$wh_id=($_GET["wh"]);
$wh_qr=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM warehouse WHERE warehouseid = '$wh_id';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($wh_qr);
echo $row['name'];
```

Please do note that you should stop using `mysql_*` functions since they're deprecated, you also need to validate and sanitize whatever user input you get. start using `PDO` or `Mysqli` and start using `prepared statements`.

Comment: It does not work...
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index2.php on line 20

Comment: @user3101966 small typo, fixed. try it now.

Comment: That's because the answer contains `mysql_` functions instead of `mysqli_` @user3101966 which is "one" of the problems. I asked you to show us your **full** code earlier.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah sorry that's my bad, I fixed it. got used to writing mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: THANKS! That works perfectly. What about MSQLI? Is it better? Does every Database support's this? My Database is old, i just renew the web-interface. Database is from 2005...

Comment: No actually, OP's using mysql, In my answer, I mixed between the two of them and thus he got that error message, it's fixed now.

Comment: Wait a minute. The OP's error message is `mysqli_` based, yet is using `mysql_query` @AliTrixx OP is not using functions properly.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Using `mysqli_` or PDO is suggested. @user3101966

Comment: @user3101966 Mysqli is more secure than mysql, also mysql got deprecated starting PHP 5.5, it should support most databases, you can try and see.

Comment: @user3101966 Also, if my answer was the correct answer then choosing it as the correct answer would be helpful.